# Не меняется картинка на сайте

Tags: html, wordpress

Нужно изменить картинку в одном разделе на сайте. Сайт: самописная тема на вордпресс.

Вроде всё легко, загрузил на хостинг, после изменил в `index.php` путь. Но картинка на сайте не отображается. Путь верный, на хостинге картинка есть, не могу понять, в чём проблема.

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> 
    <div class="box_rev">
    <img class="box_img" alt="альтернативный текст" src="/wp- content/themes/img/rev_3.jpg"> 
    <a href="адрес статьи" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> <span>Перейти<br> 
     к статье</span> </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Кэширование на сайте отключал. И ещё, если указать путь на картинку, которая уже есть на сайте в другом месте, то в разделе она отображаться будет. Может есть какое-то запрещение на изменение картинок или в чём дело? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Привиедите пожалуйста пример кода и что конкретно у вас не получается, пока трудно понять что вы сделали, и что не получилось

Comment: ЧТо на месте картинки? Ничего?

Comment: @BroouzerKing 
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
   <div class="box_rev">
   <img class="box_img" alt="" src="/wp- 
     content/themes/img/rev_3.jpg">
    <a href="адрес статьи" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> 
    <span>Перейти<br>
            к статье</span>
     </a>
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: @Эникейщик  добавил картинку с тем,что выводит. Ну саму картинку не подгружает , alt показывает

Comment: В адрес затесался пробел, наверняка он там не нужен.

Comment: а что за сайт? как посмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

В данном пути нету указанной темы. В папке wp-contents должна бить папка themes а в ней должны бить папки с темами. Какая тема активна? посмотри в админе в панели "Внешний Вид/Темы"

```
/wp- content/themes/img/rev_3.jpg
```

В пути есть пробел, его нужно удалить
или замените строчку на это

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/img/rev_3.jpg
```

если все же хочется прописать правильный путь то нужно добавить папку с темой (ну и в этой папке с темой должна бить папка "img" в которой и лежит файл "rev_3.jpg", если не так, то переместите папку с файлом в активную тему)

```
/wp-content/themes/THEMES_NAME_FOLDER/img/rev_3.jpg
```

Comment: Пробел появился когда я сюда вставил код,и название темы тоже есть,убрал так как там название сайта повторяется. @AndriyJ

Comment: попробуйте тогда
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/img/rev_3.jpg

Comment: спасибо за помощь,но все равно не отображается(